# Sum alignment in equations

Tags: math-mode, align

What is the best way to align equal signs and sum symbols in the following MWE?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{4}
y_\text{L} = & \sum_{s=1}^n \left( Y_s \, \lambda_s \right) & \quad &
             \\
         x = & \sum_{s=1}^n \left( X_s \, \lambda_s \right) & \quad & x \geq 0
             \\
             & \sum_{s=1}^n \lambda_s = 1 & \quad & \lambda_s \geq 0
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

This is not perfect but works. As far as I know `&=` should be preferred over `=&` since the latter causes the space shrieked. But I cannot achieve desired alignment with `&=`.

Comment: Could you please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. Could you also show an example of the output you get now and the output you want?

Comment: On compiling, it looks OK to me. One might consider another layout if the last line doesn't have the same semantic status as the two above.

Comment: It compiles, but the horizontal space between `=` and `Σ` is smaller than I would like (I'd like it to be as in the ordinary `\begin{equation} y_\mathrm{L} = \sum_{s=1}^n (Y_s \, \lambda_s) \end{equation}`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please clarify what exactly you want to achieve! Here is your code how I would have written it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{alignedat}{2}
    y_\mathrm{L} &= \sum_{s=1}^n (Y_s \, \lambda_s)\\
    x &= \sum_{s=1}^n (X_s \, \lambda_s) &&\qquad x \geq 0\\
    &\mathrel{\hphantom{=}} \sum_{s=1}^n \lambda_s = 1 &&\qquad \lambda_s \geq 0\\
    \sum_{s=1}^n \lambda_s &= 1 &&\qquad \lambda_s \geq 0
    \end{alignedat}
    \end{equation}  
\end{document}
```

You may decide if you want to have the last or the previous line.

[image]

Please note that the use of `\left(` and `\right)` is not needed here and does change the spacing. For this very case, `\sum_{s=1}^nY_s\lambda_s` would be enough to be understood right.

If you like, you may write `x_{\phantom{s}}\geq 0` in order to get the inequalities aligned as well.

Comment: It looks very good. I'll go this way. Can you, please, explain how `\mathrel{\hphantom{=}}` differs from _e.g._ `\phantom{{}={}}` or `\phantom{{}=}`.

Answer (score 0):

very simple use `&=` in the first two equation on the third line you add `\quad` in front of equation as shown below:

```
\begin{alignedat}{4}

y_\text{L} &= \sum_{s=1}^n \left( Y_s \, \lambda_s \right) & \quad &\\

   x       &= \sum_{s=1}^n \left( X_s \, \lambda_s \right) & \quad & x \geq 0\\

         & \quad\sum_{s=1}^n \lambda_s = 1 & \quad & \lambda_s \geq 0
\end{alignedat}
```

All the three lines will be perfectly aligned.

Comment: This is the easiest way, indeed. But it is not 'perfectly' aligned. The `\quad` is a bit (5.2626 % :-)) to small.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi is 100 % right. It's easy, but not perfectly aligned.